# Help, after updating mono Tomboy Notes is no longer working

Tags: 14.04, mono, tomboy

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

when I try run Tomboy Notes via command line I get the following error:

`$ tomboy`

```
Unhandled Exception:
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'gtk-sharp, Version=2.12.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=35e10195dab3c99f' or one of its dependencies.
File name: 'gtk-sharp, Version=2.12.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=35e10195dab3c99f'
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'gtk-sharp, Version=2.12.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=35e10195dab3c99f' or one of its dependencies.
File name: 'gtk-sharp, Version=2.12.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=35e10195dab3c99f'
```

my mono version is `$ mono --version`

```
Mono JIT compiler version 4.2.1 (Stable 4.2.1.102/6dd2d0d Sun Nov 22 14:45:58 SAST 2015)
Copyright (C) 2002-2014 Novell, Inc, Xamarin Inc and Contributors. www.mono-project.com
    TLS:           __thread
    SIGSEGV:       altstack
    Notifications: epoll
    Architecture:  amd64
    Disabled:      none
    Misc:          softdebug 
    LLVM:          supported, not enabled.
    GC:            sgen
```

any suggestions on how I may resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

[Resolved]

Using `Synaptic Package Manager` I removed everything related to `mono`.

Then I re-install `tomboy` via `Ubuntu Software Center`.

When `tomboy` gets installed it will also install `mono` , therefore version now installed is:

```
$ mono --version
Mono JIT compiler version 3.2.8 (Debian 3.2.8+dfsg-4ubuntu1.1)
Copyright (C) 2002-2014 Novell, Inc, Xamarin Inc and Contributors. www.mono-project.com
    TLS:           __thread
    SIGSEGV:       altstack
    Notifications: epoll
    Architecture:  amd64
    Disabled:      none
    Misc:          softdebug 
    LLVM:          supported, not enabled.
    GC:            sgen
```

All is fine now.